# Modificar dados de acesso ao banco de dados no arquivo app.config depois de rodar o "publish" do projeto

Tags: c#, mysql, linux

Olá, criei uma aplicação em C# e para acesso ao banco de dados fiz o seguinte procedimento:
No arquivo app.config criei o seguinte:

```
<add name="MyDatabase"
    connectionString="server=192.168.10.100;user id=usuario;password=senha;database=nomeDataBase";providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

Após isso, nos meus codigos chamei as conexões assim:

```
var constring=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Mydatabase"].ConnectionString;
```

Até ai tudo bem, na maquina qual desenvolvi isso funciona perfeitamente, porém, se levo isso para outro host e tento mudar o servidor mysql(linux - 192.168.10.100) por um outro da rede (linux também - 192.168.10.110) ele não se conecta, mesmo mudando as informações do App.config. É como se ainda estivesse com os dados do servidor de testes.
Como posso fazer para alterar esses valores visto que terei por exemplo que usar mais de um servidor em casos diferentes e ficar compilando e publicando o projeto as vezes é um trabalho desnecessário.

Comment: Informe mais detalhes, é uma aplicação web, um service ou o que? Você reiniciou o processo ou pool da aplicação após alterar o `app.config`?

Comment: É uma aplicação desktop usando windows forms, sobre mudar os dados da aplicação eu não cheguei a fazer o reinicio do serviço.
Apenas fui no diretório gerado pelo VS, lá tem um diretório chamado Aplication Files, um arquivo do tipo .Aplication e um setup.
Dentro do diretorio Aplication modifiquei o arquivo "NomedoPrograma.exe.config.deploy", nele inseri as informações do servidor mysql.

Comment: Usando `Transformation` é o jeito mais fácil, realmente.

Comment: Modificar o pacote de instalação depois de gerado não é uma boa ideia @banana

Comment: Uma dica, deixa um campo TEXTO aonde você digita o endereço e ele conecta neste endereço digitado, aí você pode trocar sem modificar o arquivo.